# Mongo update to 3.2 gives error 'GridFS: Index with name: files_id_1_n_1 already exists with different options'

Tags: mongodb

After updating mongo from 3.0 to 3.2, I get the following error when trying to put a new file in my gridFS with mongofiles:

> 2016-10-25T15:23:10.765+0200  Failed: error while storing 'execute.sh' intoGridFS: Index with name: files_id_1_n_1 already exists with different options

As a result the files are partially inserted in the GridFS. I can see the entries in the collections .chunks and .files but I cannot get the stored files with mongofiles or Java driver.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to drop the .file collection index files_id_1_n_1.
I did it with robomongo but you can do it also directly with mongo console

`db.getCollection('configs.chunks').dropIndex('files_id_1_n_1')`

Then I just put a new file with mongofiles and it has recreated the index.
I have re-indexed by security but maybe it was not necessary.

`db.getCollection('configs.chunks').reIndex()`

I did not see any difference between the two indexes and maybe my solution is not the best one but it worked.